# Can a container run in Azure IoT Edge access a monitor to visualize data?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

We are looking at using Azure IoT Edge Runtime for running loads that would ingest sensor data from an assembly robot in our factory. We would also run a stream analytics workload to analyze data. The data should also be visualized.

If the machine running IoT Edge runtime is hooked up to a monitor, could a container in the runtime show a GUI on the monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically some people seem to have done this. This is not anything that would be specific to Azure IoT Edge but is a generic Docker problem. See for example [here](https://dev.to/darksmile92/run-gui-app-in-linux-docker-container-on-windows-host-4kde).

Generally, what people most do (in Docker context but also in specific with IoT Edge) is something like:

- Run a light-weight web server inside your container / module and expose it's port to the host.
- On the host, have a web browser running and access the web server of the container to display the actual content.